# Is there a canonical way to "fix" a "dynamic" IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

[IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) does not guarantee that enumerating twice will yield the same result. In fact, it's quite easy to create an example where `myEnumerable.First()` returns different values when executed twice:

```
class A {
    public A(string value) { Value = value; }
    public string Value {get; set; } 
}

static IEnumerable<A> getFixedIEnumerable() {
    return new A[] { new A("Hello"), new A("World") };
}

static IEnumerable<A> getDynamicIEnumerable() {
    yield return new A("Hello");
    yield return new A("World");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<A> fix = getFixedIEnumerable();
    IEnumerable<A> dyn = getDynamicIEnumerable();

    Console.WriteLine(fix.First() == fix.First()); // true
    Console.WriteLine(dyn.First() == dyn.First()); // false
}
```

This is not just an academic example: Using the popular `from ... in ... select new A(...)`  will create exactly this situation. This can lead to unexpected behaviour:

```
fix.First().Value = "NEW";
Console.WriteLine(fix.First().Value); // prints NEW

dyn.First().Value = "NEW";
Console.WriteLine(dyn.First().Value); // prints Hello
```

**I understand why this happens.** I also know that this could be fixed by executing `ToList()` on the Enumerable or by overriding `==` for class `A`. That's not my question.

The question is: When you write a method that takes an arbitrary IEnumerable and you want the property that the sequence is only evaluated once (and then the references are "fixed"), what's the canonical way to do this? `ToList()` seems to be used mostly, but if the source is fixed already (for example, if the source is an array), the references are copied to a list (unnecessarily, since all I need is the fixed property). Is there something more suitable or is `ToList()` the "canonical" solution for this issue?

Comment: By definition doesn't an IEnumerable say that order is not guaranteed? If order is required for your implementation you are using the wrong datatype, no? All you're asking for in your contract with IEnumerable is that the elements can be traversed IE: As you say, a list is better suited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToList` is very definitely the way to go.

It has some optimisations: if the input enumeration is an `ICollection` (e.g. an array or list) it will call `ICollection.CopyTo` to copy the collection to an array rather than actually enumerating - so the cost is unlikely to be significant unless the collection is enormous.

IMHO, in general it is better for most methods to return `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`, **unless** you want to hint to consumers of the method that the implementation may use lazy evaluation (e.g. yield).

In cases where a method should return an immutable list, return a readonly wrapper (`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`) e.g. by calling `ToList().AsReadOnly()`, but still return the interface type `IList<T>`.

If you follow this guideline, consumers of the method won't ever need an unnecessary call to `ToList`.

Answer (score 2):

You mean if your function takes a parameter and you want to make sure the parameter is not lazy, because you need to iterate over it more than once in the method?  I typically make the parameter an `ICollection` instead in that case, making it the responsibility of the caller to reify the enumerable if it's lazy.

Answer (score 2):

The `IEnumerable` interface just give "a way" to iterate through elements (creating a IEnumerable from a linq query is a perfect example as `IEnumerable` is like a SQL query for a database).  It will always be dynamic until you store the result into an `ICollection` (ToList, ToArray), so the iteration is processed until the end and the result stored in a "fixed" way.

Answer (score 1):

The most common problem is stated by Joel Spolsky in his [Law of Leaky Abstractions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html). Having `IEnumerable` parameter in your method you expect an object that just can be enumerated and nothing more. But nevertheless you do care of the passed collection whether it is "fixed" or "dynamic". You can see that abstraction made by `IEnumerable` is leaked. There is no solution that fits well for all cases. In your case you can pass `List<T>` or `T[]` (or some other types you expect to be actual types for parameters in your method) instead of `IEnumerable`. The most common advise is to realize your abstraction and design your code with respect to it.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you've explained your question, it seems you want to enumerate a sequence multiple times and get the same ordering each time. This implies you're either holding onto a reference to the sequence to perform iterations later, or you're doing comparisons multiple times within the same method.

Generally speaking, when accepting an `IEnumerable<T>` which you mean to keep a reference to or manipulate more than once, it's safer to copy the sequence to an internal representation. My preference is to use the `ToList()` extension, as it's very well-understood and possibly the simplest collection with a predictable ordering.

Internally, the .NET Framework tends to use `List<T>` whenever an "general" collection is required.